# How to debug error 502 on Apache2 reverse proxy with HTTPS ? "Error reading from remote server returned by /"

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, https

I'm not able to solve this error while trying to configure a reverse proxy in Apache2 to redirect trafic into a Docker container.

I've see several people online trying to tweak `timeout` parameter on `ProxyPass` but it did not work

The thing is the Proxy works fine when interacting with port 80 without https but once i use port 443 and try to make it work for HTTPS trafic, it returns a 502 Proxy Error with the message `Error reading from remote server returned by /`

here is the mydomaine-le-ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

       ServerName mydomaine.tld
       ProxyPreserveHost On

       SSLProxyEngine On
       SSLProxyVerify none
       SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

       ProxyPass / https://localhost:8081/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
       ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8081/
       ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain locahost mydomaine.tld

       ErrorLog /srv/logs/error/mydomaine.log
       CustomLog /srv/logs/access/mydomaine.log combined


       SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomaine.tld/fullchain.pem
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomaine.tld/privkey.pem
       SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomaine.tld/chain.pem
       Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check the Apache's error log and that of `localhost:8081`. My guess is, that on `localhost:8081` the server is using HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: You have 'SSLProxyEngine On', which is telling httpd that it should use https to connect to the backend; as @PiotrP.Karwasz mentioned, you have https://localhost:8081, so that should be an HTTPS endpoint. That would be ususual for a port 8081. You probably want 'SSLEngine On', remove 'SSLProxyEngine', and change https://localhost:8081/ to http://localhost:8081/, which assumes your backend is just HTTP

Comment: Thanks to both you and made it working! I Replaced SSLProxyEngine with SSLEngine and switched the backed to http so it would stay coherent all the way to the external domain. It worked. Thanks a lot. I've been struggling on and off with this for 3 days.